# What kind of data is received from our app to flurry?

Tags: android

i am developing one app related to flurry.

my code is as fallowing.

```
         @Override
    protected void onStart() 
    {
        super.onStart();
         FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "key);

    }
       @Override
    protected void onStop() 
    {

        super.onStop();
        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);


    }
```

it working fine and it shows my app satus in flurry.

But i want to know about which type of data is sent from my app to flurry.

If any one know the solution please help me

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you observe the permission that required by Flurry

**Required Permission:**

```
android.permission.INTERNET
```

Required to send analytics data back to the flurry servers

**Optional Permission:**

`android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

If your application has location permissions, analytics will track where your application is being used. Without this, only country level location information will be available. To disable detailed location reporting even when your app has permission, call `FlurryAgent.setReportLocation(false)` before calling `FlurryAgent.onStartSession()` and no detailed location information will be sent.

**So which type of data is sent from my app to flurry**

*Agent sends session count, session length, session per page, device type, network type, OS version of device generally. And as optional Agent can send location of user to server*

There are more features which can be used in your app

[image]

Read the document file they provided with sdk, [FAQ](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/technical-info.html).

Comment: Hi if u don't mind please tell me how flurry get data from our app.

Comment: Read FAQ of flurry, I added link in my answer. If you are asking about internal work, I have no idea.